# Bit-length function that returns msb '1' and lsb '1'

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need a function that can return the length from the most significant 'on'-bit to the least significant 'on'-bit. How would you go about making such an function? Im thinking of something in the lines of subtracting some value $x$ from the standard bit-length function:

$BL(n)=1+\lfloor log_2(n)\rfloor$

or

$BL(n)=\lceil log_2(n+1)\rceil$

so the function in question is:

$F(n) = BL(n) - x$

what is $x$ here, is it has something to do with pow2?

I provide a table that should show what values to expect:

```
n  binary    F(n)
0  00000     0
1  00001     1
2  00010     1
3  00011     2
4  00100     1
5  00101     3
6  00110     2
7  00111     3
```

The sequence $0,1,1,2,1,3,2,3,1,4,3,4,2,4,3,4,1...$ does not match in the OEIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the 2-adic valutation of $n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). Let
$$
v_2(n) = k \text{ if } n = 2^km \text{ with $m$ odd.}
$$

Then
$$
F(n) = 1 + \log_2 n - v_2(n).
$$

Comment: Thanks. I have little understanding of what 2-adic (or p-adic) means. It looks to me that 2-adic is similar to binary number and boolean algebra. I wonder if they are essentially the same thing or if 2-adics are different. If they are same why use the term 2-adics.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime number, the $p$-adic valutation of another number is "how many factors $p$ the other number has". Of course 2-adic valutation has more than something to do with binary representation.